# Counting number of words like microsoft count

Tags: php

I need to count number of words in ms word 2007 format using php, the problem is that the counting needs to be the same as it works in Microsoft Word, because I try to writing code but not 100% count words like ms word count. 
My script:
    //library from: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8908-PHP-Convert-DOCX-DOC-PDF-to-plain-text.html
require_once("includes/library_count_words.php");

$fileDir = $_FILES["docfile"]["name"];

$docObj = new Doc2Txt($fileDir);

$text = $docObj->convertToText();

```
$text = preg_replace('![^ \pL\pN\s]+!u', '', strtolower($text));
$text = trim( preg_replace('![ \s]+!u', ' ', $text) );

$count = count( explode(' ', $text) );

print "<div class='alert alert-success'>Number of words : ".$count."</div>";
```

}

Any suggestion guys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one, but still not 100% same.

```
function str_word_count_utf8($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[\'&_,%`"@~#]/', "", $str);
    //$str = preg_replace('/[&_,%`"@~#]/', "", $str);
    //$a = preg_split('/\W+/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    //$a = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
    $a = preg_split('/\S+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    return count($a);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting starts with extraction of text from your file. If we speak about using just php, it means that you don*t have any other option - I mean, you can`t open it in your MS Office installed on your server, etc.

So, the first and the most important thing to do is to extract text from your file. Depending on your file extension, you can use various libraries out there - PHPWord, for example. Things are easier with DOCX files, since this is a zipped archive of structured files you can use to extract text. DOC files are less easy, because parsing a DOC file means that you grab both text and pictures-related data from such a file, resulting in a certain amount of garbage added to meaningful text you ectracted from your DOC file.

So, if you use PHP only, the short answer is: your results will NEVER be identical to MS Word counter.

But great news is that you don*t need identical results, because you take 4 well-known counters out there (FineCount, built-in MS Word counter, PractiCount, AnycCount, etc.), you get 5 absolutely different numbers.